# Is pointer arithmetic in iterations overflow-safe?

Tags: c++, c, iteration, pointer-arithmetic

I've seen very often array iterations using plain pointer arithmetic even in newer C++ code. I wonder how safe they really are and if it's a good idea to use them. Consider this snippet (it compiles also in C if you put `calloc` in place of `new`):

```
int8_t *buffer = new int8_t[16];
for (int8_t *p = buffer; p < buffer + 16; p++) {
    ...
}
```

Wouldn't this kind of iteration result in an overflow and the loop being skipped completely when `buffer` *happens* to become allocated at address `0xFFFFFFF0` (in a 32 bit address space) or `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0` (64 bit)?
As far as I know, this would be an exceptionally unlucky, but still possible circumstance.

Comment: Yes it would probably result in an overflow in that case. But no sane operating system is going to map memory at those addresses for you anyway.

Comment: is pointer overflow defined behavior?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is there a guarantee for that?

Comment: I would use direct inequality rather than "less than". I.e. `p != (buffer + 16)` would be acceptable for what you're doing.

Comment: @WhozCraig Using inequality would fail the very first comparison.

Comment: @Dave because 0xFFFFFFF0 == 0x0 on your rig ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Were you not referring to the code in the question? You said "use direct inequality rather than 'less than'". Thus, it becomes `for (int8_t *p = buffer; p != (buffer + 16); p++) { ... }`, which will fail the first check no matter what... long before the overflow you are trying to prevent.

Comment: @Dave that was precisely what I meant, as the expression was straight from my comment. And I did not say I was trying to "prevent" an overflow.   And in your response you didn't answer my question. On your rig `0xFFFFFFF0 == 0x0` using 32bit values ?? [Thats interesting](http://ideone.com/kfugYO).

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I'm not sure what I was thinking last night... whatever it was, it makes no sense to me now.

Comment: @Dave Lolz. Glad I'm not the only one. I hope it at least makes sense how inequality should work, precisely because if an overflow happens, it should happen on both the incremented variable (`p` in this case) and the expression (`buffer+16`) and though I concur it is still ripe with UB on the overflow side, at least there's confidence its "consistently" UB =P

Answer (score 8):

This is safe.  The C and C++ standards explicitly allow you to calculate a pointer value that points one item beyond the end of an array, and to compare a pointer that points within the array to that value.

An implementation that had an overflow problem in the situation you describe would simply not be allowed to place an array right at the end of memory like that.

In practice, a more likely problem is `buffer + 16` comparing equal to `NULL`, but this is not allowed either and again a conforming implementation would need to leave an empty place following the end of the array.

Comment: I have fog on the brain tonight. Is lesser-comparison of pointer-types noted in the standard(s)? I know equality and inequality are, but honestly can't remember the other relational-ops.

Comment: @WhozCraig the relational operators are defined for pointer types but they are only allowed for comparing pointers into the same array otherwise it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Simple Roger that. I just found it in C99 §6.5.8,p5, including the specificity you mentioned about residing in the same array region. I assume similar specification is in C++ as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Since `p` is always inside the range of the allocation, `<` and friends are well-defined.

Comment: @rici ya, as commented prior, the standard covers it in the noted section (the C standard, but I'm quite sure its in the C++ standard likewise).

Comment: @WhozCraig: 5.9 p2 last sentence: "If two pointers point to elements of the same array or one beyond the end of the array, the pointer to the object with the higher subscript compares higher."

Comment: @rici Good one, if you bother writing an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Simple: Pointers to members of the same struct or same union may also be compared.